# Checkbox in WPF DataGrid header only?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to add a checkbox (in addition to text) to a column header in a WPF DataGrid? That is, without using DataGridCheckBoxColumn, which would add checkboxes to all grid cells in that particular column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
<my:DataGrid Margin="72,59,6,3" Name="DataGrid1" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" >
          <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1">
                <my:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate> 
                </my:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate> 
            </my:DataGridTextColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns> 
    </my:DataGrid>
```

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you..happy 2018

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to get the checked state?